# bootstrap 4 tabs content одинаковая высота | bootstrap 4 tabs content same height

Tags: tabs, bootstrap4, modal

1. Я добавил табы от bootstrap-4 в модальное окно от bootstrap-4.
2. Модальное окно я центрировал стандартным методом: добавив класс **modal-dialog-centered**.
3. Теперь, если в табах находится разный по высоте контент, происходит неприятный сдвиг модального окна, при переключении табов.

**Вопрос:** как сделать одинаковую высоту контента у каждого таба, чтобы при переключении модальное окно оставалось неподвижным?

**Пример**(сделан из примеров в документации bootsrap-4):

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- begin Tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
            <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end Tabs -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: чего минусов то столько?

Comment: @kizoso Здравствуйте. Мой ответ кажется верен. Я сам искал на этот вопрос ответ и не нашел. Когда уже сам реализовал, решил с другими поделиться и написал в стиле: вопрос и сразу ответ. А минусов столько, как я считаю, потому что у меня на данном ресурсе есть ряд недоброжелателей(видимо у них что-то личное против меня) и они смело творят несправедливость.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Решение:**

**1.** Возьмем обработчик модального окна, который срабатывает после открытия модального окна, и добавим туда следующий код:

**Результат:**

```js
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var maxHeight = 0;

  $('.tab-pane').each(function() {
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height("").height());
  }).height(maxHeight);
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- begin Tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end Tabs -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Данный код срабатывает после открытия модального окна, находит максимальную высоту контента одного из табов, далее задает остальным данную высоту.
Теперь наше модальное окно неподвижно при переключении вкладок.

**2.** Добавим обработчик на ресайз окна, чтобы высота блоков с контентом оставалась корректной при ресайзе окна.

**Результат:**

```js
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var maxHeight = 0;

  $('.tab-pane').each(function() {
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height("").height());
  }).height(maxHeight);
})

/* begin Window Resize */
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeThrottler, false);

var resizeTimeout;

function resizeThrottler() {
  if (!resizeTimeout) {
    resizeTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
      resizeTimeout = null;
      actualResizeHandler();
    }, 66);
  }
}

function actualResizeHandler() {

  /* begin Modal Tabs */
  var maxHeight = 0;

  $('.tab-pane').each(function() {
    maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, $(this).height("").height());
  }).height(maxHeight);
  /* end Modal Tabs */

}
/* end Window Resize */
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
      Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- begin Tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
          <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos nobis laborum id modi cupiditate. Voluptas necessitatibus numquam pariatur assumenda aut aspernatur reprehenderit ab possimus laudantium laboriosam, repellat porro id illo.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end Tabs -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Тада! Готово.**